# Subscribe to an XML-Message in another BizTalk application

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

we've started to use BizTalk in our company and now I am facing the following scenario which I am not sure how to properly implement.

**Scenario**

There is an application, let's say com.xmlapp, that receives data and constructs an XML message  in its orchestration. There are other applications, com.app1, com.app2 etc, that should subscribe to that XML message and map it to different messages to be sent to other systems.

**Question**

How can I achieve that? Should I reference the applications and configure the ports for each application or how can I properly subscribe to just that specific message form other orchestrations?

What I also read is that I can send the XML message to the message box and subscribe directly to it but I don't know exactly how to do that.

Comment: For send ports you can subscribe by going to the filter section and specifying the filter as "root-node-name#namespace".  This assumes messages your posted messages have the "messagetype" property set (you can see that in the 'context' portion of tracked message events). It's very similar for orchestrations.

Answer (score 2):

Usually if the Orchestration references the same scheme you are better of having it in the same BizTalk application.

You can have your BizTalk Application reference another BizTalk Application, but then if you want to redeploy your referenced application, you have to uninstall the referencing application first.

The other option would be to separate your schema into a Common project and have them in a Common BizTalk application.  This way if the schema needs changing you can change the assembly version number and deploy that side by side and independently update the Orchestrations.

For an Orchestration to subscribe directly to a message in the message box, just set create the logical port in the Orchestration as Direct, and link it to a Receive shape in the Orchestration that has the message type you want to subscribe to.

Comment: What 'Access Restrictions' should be set for the ports to the message box? Should I stick to 'Internal' or do I need to set it to 'Public' for the other orchestration to be able to get the message?

Comment: @AlexK That setting has not impact on their ability to get the message, it is just allowing others to re-use the port type or not.